# Canon no longer makes CanoScan 8800F AC adapters, help needed to replicate its functionality

Tags: dc

The CanoScan 8800F uses a proprietary 32VDC AC adapter that's no longer manufactured. A Flickr user did the trial and error to find out how to modify another 32VDC AC adapter for use with the 8800f. It seems simple enough. One pin carries the 32VDC of current, and other pin carrying current starts off carrying current through a resistor only to have that resistor shorted after a few seconds so that the full 32VDC of current can be delivered. Could someone advise me what the parts and schematics would be to build "a time delay relay assembly" to "short a 1.5k ohm resistor" "after a few seconds" of the scanner being powered on?

I tried messaging the user to get a more detailed answer, but to no avail. I figure he assumed that if you have more electronics knowledge his solution would be easy to interpret. Here is his original post from Flickr:

"Here is the real deal. I purchased Canon Canoscan 8800F with no power adapter. After extensive testing here is how it works. Looking at the back of the scanner the left pin will be referred to as pin 1, center pin as pin 2 and right pin as pin 3. Now, I had to build a circuit which adds a time delay. Let me tell you how to get your scanner to work. Pin 2 is ground, Pin 3 is 32VDC. Pin 1 wants the same as pin 3 (32VDC) with the following exceptions: when pin 3 receives 32VDC pin 1 will receive the same 32VDC BUT in series must be 1.5k ohms. Then, after a few seconds, the 1.5k ohm resistor must be shorted allowing the full 32VDC to be applied to pin 1. I built a time delay relay assembly to facilitate this function and now the scanner will power on when the power button is pressed. Hope this helps."

https://www.flickr.com/groups/767295@N20/discuss/72157627293403452/72157647465205394

Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone know the purpose of such functionality? Some kind of in-rush current limiting?

Comment: Sounds like it should be doable with a relay, a 555 timer IC, a 5V regulator (to supply the 555 IC) and associated resistors/capacitors.

Comment: So the scanner does startup checks, loads the power supply, which then ramps voltage on pin one? It could be inrush limiting, but this sounds more procedural than that. Like signaling power_good or something.

Comment: Or you know,  just a bs reason to limit the second hand market and price gorge on replacement parts.

Comment: @Passerby LOL, I was hoping it's not actually that. But yeah, probably.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a job for "time delay relay"/"delay-on relay". You have three options:

- Buy industrial 24V units. They are beautify and expensive. Example:
  http://www.alliedelec.com/schneider-electric-magnecraft-822td10h-uni/70185255/ ($57)
- Buy cheap relays from ebay:

  - http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-DC-12V-Delay-Adjustable-Timer-Relay-Switch-Module-0-to-10-Second-/261852010468 -- this one is $1 with free shipping, but it is 12V only so it will also 12v power source.
  - http://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-24V-1-Channel-Relay-Module-switch-on-delay-turn-on-up-to-1-hour-relay-24V/221522754320 -- this one is $8 and I think it does what you need if it will survive 32 volt (you never know what the real max voltage of '24V' circuit is)
- Assemble one. Most 555 circuits cannot operate off 32V DC, so use transitor based circuit such as this one:
  http://www.bowdenshobbycircuits.info/page2.htm#delay.gif
  This one has great property that three transistors would limit the voltage on capacitor, so there is no need for high voltage capacitor. You will want to increase 10K resistor to 20-40K and use a relay which can handle 32 volts (or add an extra resistor to 12 V relay)

Answer (score 3):

If you want a time delay circuit to build yourself, here's one for you -- the TL431 is a wonderfully underrated part, capable of serving as a comparator/reference combo in addition to being a programmable shunt reference.  The IRF7540 can be replaced by any standard gate (i.e. Rds(on) at 10V Vgs) power PMOSFET, and the timing capacitor should be a stable, low-leakage type such as a polyester film or a good grade of tantalum cap -- the current values are chosen for a 3s delay-ON in the simulation and *will need to be tweaked* for a real TL431. Also, the inrush limiter resistor should be rated for at least 1W.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxgcUl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As to how this thing works -- U1 (represented by the cobbled-together macromodel in the dotted box because CircuitLab, in their infinite wisdom, does not provide a TL431) is used open-loop as a comparator, turning ON when Ctiming charges to 2.5V via Rtiming, while R2 holds Q1 and Q2 off until U1 turns on. (SW-IC is used to set the initial condition for Ctiming to 0V as CircuitLab lacks SPICE's .IC command.)  When U1 turns on, it pulls its cathode to about 2V above the anode -- D1 adds another 18V of voltage drop atop that to keep Q1s gate from being pulled beyond its absolute voltage rating (i.e. to keep Q1 from going bang).  Once U1 is solidly ON, Q1 and Q2 both switch ON, shorting out Rlimiter (i.e. the 1.5kΩ resistor from the spec) and pulling U1's adjust terminal HIGH through R1 in order to prevent noise from causing the output to chatter (in other words, Q2 and R1 turn the TL431 into a crude Schmitt trigger).  RL serves as a demonstration load.

Answer (score 2):

@ThreePhaseEel has a good approach; I'd simplify the circuitry somewhat,
because there doesn't seem to be need for accuracy or sharp turnon.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4J0fb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you want a sharper turnon, R4 can be replaced with a 24V zener diode.